# Regex to filter numbers after a text

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

Can you help me with this example please:

```
BUILTIN\s+\d{1,2}
```

https://regex101.com/r/w7A3H7/1

I only want to filter out the numbers after text `BUILTIN` and before the `x` character. Now the result also contains the word `BUILTIN`, what I want to be removed.

I also can't simply use `\d{1,2}x` because I must make sure it is after the second occurance of the word `BUILTIN`. Thank you

Comment: You may use capture group: `BUILTIN\s+(\d+)x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern:

```
BUILTIN\s+\K\d+(?=x)
```

- `BUILTIN` Literal substring.
- `\s+` Match whitespace, one or more occurrences.
- `\K` Reset operator which resets the match.
- `\d+` Match digits.
- `(?=x)` Positive lookahead which ensures that after the digits a `x` is present.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/w7A3H7/2):

---

If you are working with a regex flavor which does not support the reset operator, you can use:

```
(?<=BUILTIN\s{11})\d+(?=x)
```

- `(?<=BUILTIN\s{11})` Lookbehind for literal substring followed by 11 whitespaces.
- `\d+` Match digits.
- `(?=x)` Positive lookahead which ensures that after the digits a `x` is present.

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/w7A3H7/4)

---

```
Match 1
Full match  57-59   `48`
Match 2
Full match  137-138 `4`
Match 3
Full match  283-285 `24`
Match 4
Full match  363-365 `48`
```

Comment: Thank you, almost there. \k is not supported in Python, so I use the second example. The problem, is that I can't assert 11 char length space, could be any length. The next works : https://regex101.com/r/w7A3H7/5 but still there is something to resolve : I don't need spaces in the result, only digits.
Any idea

Comment: Right, in that case you have to [use a capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/w7A3H7/8)